# Set port for ProxyPass response

Tags: apache, http, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am using a VirtualHost with ProxyPass to redirect incoming traffic on port 80 to my Spring Boot Tomcat instance on port 1337. The problem I have now is that the response is sent over port 1337. Is there any way I can get the response to be sent over port 80 as well?

Comment: How did you observe that "response is sent over port 1337"?

Comment: @DusanBajic The router denied the request. That is where I found out it was blocking the port 1337.

Comment: Are VirtualHost with ProxyPass and Spring Boot Tomcat on the same server?

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes.

Comment: And the router is somewhere between your client/browser and that server?

Comment: @DusanBajic Exactly.

Comment: There is no need to open port 1337 on router, tcp connection is established between    random source port on client IP, and port 80 on webserver IP address. There is something else wrong here. Can you test using `curl -v  http://webserver.example.com:80/` (from client side) and provide the output (remove any confidential info)